# ¿Es posible crear un PopUp en java?

Tags: java, jsp

He buscado en la net, pero solo habla de Java Swing. Hice una aplicación web con asp y servlet. El tema es que si en una consulta a la DB esta resulta vacía (no encuentra resultado), me devuelva un PopUp que diga: no se encontró resultado, pero no encuentro como hacerlo, por eso mi pregunta de si es posible hacerlo.
Actualmente solo se redirecciona al index, pero me pidieron que le pusiera eso.

Comment: Tendrás que hacer el pop up en el navegador del cliente. Eso quiere decir html / javascript, no java. Inténtalo y si encuentras problemas al crear un popup en el navegador entonces puedes preguntar aquí.

Comment: ocupe un archivo html como auxiliar para poder realizar el pop up
    <body>
       <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("BARCODE no encontrado");
            window.location.href='index.jsp';
       </script> 
     </body>

Comment: El popup, ventanas modales y ese tipo de cosas pertenecen a la vista. Java ejecutará las cosas de lado del servidor y ayuda a la generación de la vista, pero en este caso la vista se maneja enteramente en el navegador vía HTML/JavaScript/CSS. En este caso, si quieres crear un popup, debes utilizar HTML/JavaScript/CSS y asociar tu vista de manera que cuando no hayan resultados se llame a una acción JavaScript que muestre el popup.

Answer (score 1):

En una aplicacion web no es complicado, ejecuta `alert(mensaje)` en la vista y tendras un popup con el texto que envies en la variable `mensaje`.

Si necesitas más personalización, puedes crear un modal JSP o usar [JQuery Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

---

Para conseguirlo es importante saber DONDE se ejecuta cada cosa (aqui un resumen del flow de la petición saltandome las capas de servicio, negocio y bbdd que tiene cualquier app web:

- Envia la orden desde para realizar la consulta (CLIENTE - JavaScript)
- Realiza la consulta en la parte del servidor (SERVIDOR - Java)
- Consigue una respuesta (SERVIDOR - Java)
- Envia el resultado a la vista (SERVIDOR - Java)

  - Si tiene exito muestra el resultado de la consulta (CLIENTE - JavaScript)
  - Si falla muestra un mensaje error (CLIENTE - JavaScript)

Como puedes ver en la division final, de la misma manera que envias los resultados de la consulta exitosa, puedes enviar también el mensaje de error (o null en su defecto) hacia la vista.

Un ejemplo (muy simplificado y con [**ajax call**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)) sería así:

```
$.get("/listaTodosLosObjetos", 
{ "variable": valor } ).done(function( resultado ) {
    // error
    if(resultado == null) {
        alert("No se ha encontrado ningun registro en la base de datos");
    } else {
        // la consulta ha tenido exito
        // muestra la informacion como hasta ahora
    } 
});
```

---

**AÑADIDO:** lo anterior es la versión sencilla, optimamente deberias lanzar excepciones durante el proceso, lanzarlas en el bean y recogerlas con `.fail`, también puedes realizar acciones por defecto con `.default` en la vista:

```
$.get("/listaTodosLosObjetos", { 
    "variable": valor
})
.done(function( resultado ) {
    // la consulta ha tenido exito
    // muestra la informacion como hasta ahora
})
.fail(function() {
    alert("No se ha encontrado ningun registro en la base de datos");
})
.always(function() {
    // acciones comunes, como por ejemplo, 
    // limpiar algun campo o reiniciar variables.
    valor = "";
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Para eso puedes emplear la clase "[JOptionPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29)".

Más concretamente, si solo quieres mostrar un mensaje puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Contenido del mensaje", "Título del mensaje", 1);
```